# Метод вычисления ширины дерева

Tags: дерево

Есть такой метод, мне кажется что он всегда будет выдавать константное значение, или же он вычисляет ширину дерева? подскажите пожалуйста.

```
static class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;

    static int height(Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int left = height(node.left);
        int right = height(node.right);
        return Math.max(left, right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, он всегда будет выдавать константное значение, а именно `0`. Нужно заменить строчку `return Math.max(left, right);` на `return Math.max(left, right) + 1;`. Исправленный вариант:

```
static class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;

    static int height(Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int left = height(node.left);
        int right = height(node.right);
        return Math.max(left, right) + 1;
    }
}
```

Хочу заметить, что этот метод вычисляет не ширину дерева, а высоту, то есть расстояние от корня до самого глубокого листа. Если вы хотите вычислять не высоту, а ширину дерева, то сначала стоит определить, что такое ширина дерева. Например, можно определить её как `максимальная ширина уровня дерева`, где `ширина уровня дерева` есть число вершин, находящихся на некотором уровне, то есть на одинаковом расстоянии от корня. Тогда алгоритм вычисления ширины дерева выглядит следующим образом:

1. Найдём глубину дерева уже написанным методом. Обозначим её за `h`.
2. Всего уровней в дереве ровно `h + 1`. Заведём массив на `h + 1` элементов, в `i`-ой его ячейке будет записано число вершин на `i`-ом уровне. Изначально массив заполнен нулями.
3. Обойдём дерево любым алгоритмом, в процессе увеличивая соответствующие  ячейки массива.
4. По нашему определению ширина дерева равна максимуму элементов в этом массиве.

Собственно, код:

```
static class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;

    static int height(Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int left = height(node.left);
        int right = height(node.right);
        return Math.max(left, right) + 1;
    }

    static void dfs(Node node, int nodeHeight, int[] numberVertexesOnLevels) {
        ++numberVertexesOnLevels[nodeHeight];
        dfs(node.left, nodeHeight + 1, numberVertexesOnLevels);
        dfs(node.right, nodeHeight + 1, numberVertexesOnLevels);
    }

    static int width(Node node) {
        int height = height(node);
        int[] numberVertexesOnLevels = new int[height];
        dfs(node, 0, numberVertexesOnLevels);
        return Arrays.stream(numberVertexesOnLevels).max().getAsInt();
    }
}
```